# Why is my non-required data member giving required error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

This is really strange.  I have an asp.net MVC app and I'm doing some data validations.

I have some DateTime data members that are not required.  In fact I have removed all the annotations altogether.

This is a rewrite of a legacy internal system, so using a textbox is fine for entering dates.

For some reason, these text boxes are rendered as required! I've even gone so far as trying to remove the data-val and data-val-required attributes using jQuery.  I view the HTML with a browser debugger and the attributes are gone after the javascript runs.

What could be causing this?

```
From the Razor markup:
@Html.TextBox("MainStartDt", Model.MainStartDt.ToShortDateString(), new {@class="dateedit" })

from the view model:

public DateTime UsersAddedStartDt { get; set; }
public DateTime UsersAddedEndDt { get; set; }
```

What other info could I post to help.  This seems very simple, these should not be reuired without being declared as such.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` is non-nullable and therefore required. If you want it to be optional, make it nullable.

```
public DateTime? UsersAddedStartDt { get; set; }
```

This will apply to all non-nullable (value) types including `int`, `double`, `float`, `short`, `Guid`, `Point`, etc.

Comment: @richb01. I know :) and my pleasure.